# Where can I find out what features are getting added to the Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I'm curious what features are coming down the pipe for the new Dash feature in Unity. Where should I be looking for a blog or RSS to follow?

In particular, I'm wondering if they are going to add support for searching Chrome/Firefox bookmarks and Empathy contacts.

Edit: there is a [lens proposal](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/unity/?tags=dash) for the later

Answer (score 3):

Well you could sit in on IRC or subscribe to mailing groups, but that's not very interesting unless you are directly involved. The best place to watch new features get set up (usually in preperation for the next major release) is secondary news sites.

My personal favorites are:
[WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org)
and [OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk)

They both have RSS feeds, and update a couple times a day on average with new information.